# Examples and classification of holomorphic strips in $(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n,\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology, lagrangian-submanifolds

Consider an exact isotopy $\phi_t$ of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $\phi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)\pitchfork \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$. When trying to compute the Lagrangian Floer cohomology of $(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n, \phi, \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n)$ we will wanna look at the set of $J$-holomorphic strips $u:\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $$u(\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})\subset \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n,\;\;u(\mathbb{R}\times \{1\})\subset \phi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n),\;\;\lim_{\tau\rightarrow \infty}u(\tau,t)=x$$ and $\lim_{\tau\rightarrow -\infty}u(\tau,t)=y$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n \cap \phi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$.

Does anyone know a reference with examples of such holomorphic strips , and if there is a classification of them ?

All the examples that I know are around the case where $n=1$ and so we can actually draw the $J$-holomorphic strips.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.